# C# accessing static variable with generics (EmptyEnumerable<TElement>.Instance)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

I was looking into the implementation of:

```
 Enumerable.Empty<...>()
```

And I noticed that under the hood it employs this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Empty<TResult>() => (IEnumerable<TResult>) EmptyEnumerable<TResult>.Instance;
```

Which in turn employs this:

```
    internal class EmptyEnumerable<TElement>
    {
        public static readonly TElement[] Instance = new TElement[0];
    }
```

I can barely understand how this works. Can someone break it down for me? How does the compiler and the runtime handle this?

What I mean to say is that for every call to .Empty<>():

```
   Enumerable.Empty<string>()
   Enumerable.Empty<int>()
   Enumerable.Empty<SomeCustomClass>()
```

The runtime must construct reusable singleton / persistent class instances:

```
   EmptyEnumerable<string>
   EmptyEnumerable<int>
   EmptyEnumerable<SomeCustomClass>
```

and these instances (being singletons) never get disposed - they just get reused if we attempt a call with one of the types we have already used on .Empty<>().

Right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you are understanding this correctly for the most part, but I think that you are overestimating the cost of initialising classes. Remember that a new closed class type is only initialised for each _different_ type of `IEnumerable`. Calling `Enumerable.Empty<string>()` twice doesn't initialise `EmptyEnumerable<string>` twice, for example. How many _different_ type parameters are you going to give `Empty` in your application? I assume not hundreds/thousands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly this pattern is used for caching objects.

Each time you requested an empty array via calling `Empty` property, it returns same object always. It doesn't create new objects each `Empty` call with same `T` parameter.

EDIT: In that case, It's not creating any instance of your **SomeCustomClass**, just creates an **array of SomeCustomClass**. It doesn't matter if generic parameter type heavy to initilize or not.